# Apply <b>...</b> formatting to occurrences of wordlist in text

Tags: python

Given a list of words, I'd like to emphasize (using `<b>`...`</b>` tags) those words in a string. Without using regular expressions.

For example, I have:

```
list_of_words = ["python", "R", "Julia" ...]
a_Speech = "A paragraph about programming languages  ......R is good for statisticians . Python is good for programmers . ....."
```

The output should be

```
a_Speech = "A paragraph about programming languages  ......<b>R</b> is good for statisticians . <b>Python</b> is good for programmers . ....."
```

I tried something like:

```
def right_shift(astr, index, n):
    # shift by n = 3,n = 4  characters 

def function_name(a_speech): 

    for x in list_of_words: 
        if x in a_speech: 
             loc = a_speech.index(x) 
             right_shift(a_speech, loc, 3)
             a_speech[loc] = "<b>"

             right_shift(a_speech, loc+len(x), 4)          
             a_speech[loc+len(x)] = "</b>

    return a_speech
```

Comment: Really unclear what this user is asking.

Comment: This is not clear. Explain your problem with cleaner examples please.

Comment: C'mon guys, even though the OP's question was unclearly stated, they want to ***Apply <b>...</b> formatting to occurrences of wordlist in text***

Comment: Should the program be case sensitive or insensitive?

Comment: I've reworded the question is a bit, since some people seem to have trouble understanding what the OP is asking.

Comment: Why do I feel I'm being asked to do people's homework?

Comment: Jens, that's perfectly fine up to a point. The OP has shown some effort in getting this presumed homework done, and is now stuck at some point. The initial question was rather worded as a homework exercise as well, that didn't help.

Comment: @GuaravP You're probably better off creating a list of substrings, with "<b>" and "</b>" added at the right spots, and `join`-ing that sublist at the end, than trying to right shift strings.

Comment: See my solution. Works fully.

Comment: @GauravP: you never need to do arithmetic with indices, like `right_shift()`. Learn to use a generator, which does `yield somestring`, then string-join together the results of that iterator: `''.join(word for word in bold_specific_words(bold_words, ' .', a_Speech))`

Answer (score 0):

This works fully.
You needed to split *a_Speech* both on whitespace and then on periods, so we write a compound split-function `is_split_char()` then pass it into `itertools.groupby()`, which is a pretty neat iterator.

```
bold_words = set(word.lower() for word in ["python", "R", "Julia"])
  # faster to use a set than a list to test membership

import itertools

def bold_specific_words(bold_words, splitchars, text):
"""Generator to split on specified splitchars, and bold words in wordset, case-insensitive. Don't split contiguous blocks of splitchars. Don't discard the split chars, unlike string.split()."""

  def is_split_char(char, charset=splitchars):
    return char not in charset

  for is_splitchar, chars in itertools.groupby(text, is_split_char):
     word = ''.join(chars) # reform our word from the sub-iterators
     if word.lower() in bold_words:
         yield '<b>' + word + '</b>'
     else:
         yield word

>>> ''.join(word for word in bold_specific_words(bold_words, ' .', a_Speech))
'A paragraph about programming languages  ......<b>R</b> is good for statisticians . <b>Python</b> is good for programmers . .....'
```

Comment: This is case sensitive, so it won't match `'python'` with `'Python'`.

Comment: Not just whitespace and periods, I guess; commas, semi-colons, exclamation marks etc. Word boundaries, overall, which gets you close to using a regular expression.

Comment: @Evert: in general yes, in this case the only punctuation in the OP's text was period.

Comment: Totally rewritten, works fully. You can parameterize `is_split_char(char, charset=splitchars)` as much as you like

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work, creating a list of substrings with the details and appending them at the end:

```
def function_name(a_speech): 

    loc = 0
    substrings = []
    for word in list_of_words:
        if word in a_speech[loc:]:
             currentloc = loc
             loc = a_speech.index(word, start=currentloc)
             substrings.append(a_speech[currentloc:loc])
             substrings.append("<b>")
             substrings.append(word)
             substrings.append("</b>")
             loc += 3 + len(word) + 4

    return "".join(substrings)
```

(note: untested. You may have to figure out some of the last details)

Comment: this will match letters inside text, i.e. "<b>R</b>escue". With same success we can use `replace` with less code and more pythonic

Comment: You have to write a compound split-function, and that's not trivial. Best done as a generator, yielding substrings, instead of explicitly using indices.

Comment: @Reishin Yes, true (you mean substrings, not just letters, within words). So one's still stuck with properly finding word boundaries.